# Working with multidimensional dynamic arrays in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Suppose that I'm given an object class and an `int[]` describing the arbitrary lengths of an multi-dimensional array that I wish to instantiate (and work with). So far, I've worked out that I can use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?> type, int... sizes)`, but at that point I'm stuck. In other words,

```
Class<?> type = float.class;  // this varies (I receive this)
int[] sizes = new int[]{ 10, 400, 300 }; // this varies too, it could be e.g. int[]{0} for a scalar
Object o = (Object) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, sizes);
```

After defining `Object o` I don't know how to proceed. A priori, I don't know if `type` is going to be `float.class` or some other type (for now I assume it's a basic type). Worse than that, `int[] sizes` can be anything.

To make it a more concrete problem, how am I supposed to, say, set each element of the multi-dimensional array `o` with a given value, say `5.6` after I've instantiated it with `Array.newInstance`?

Comment: May be it's time to try something dynamic? e.g. ruby, python or javascript :)

Comment: Gladly. Except this is to work with an existing Java API (netCDF), and doing a whole lot of if-elses to account for the different cases (up to 7-dimensional arrays of anything from shorts to ints to floats to doubles to Strings) could work but it'd be a "dirty" solution. Maybe it doesn't look neat, but at least it'd work?

Comment: @dbw In the example I've provided, I'd have a way to get the class of objects in each slot of the multi-dimensional array (float.class is *one* example), and an array with the length of each of the array's dimensions. So in this case, `Object o` is really a `float[10][400][300]` -- but it could be something else e.g. `type = String.class; sizes = new int[]{0}` would be a single `String`. I hope that's more clear.

Comment: This is a brain bender! I almost have a recursive solution, but I hit a wall with `Object row = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(multiArray, i);` because get only works with one dimensional arrays. Do we have an upper bound on the number of dimensions? (Most platforms have a limit of 255, but maybe your application has a smaller limit)

Comment: @Thorn According to the netCDF API, they go as far as 8-dimensional arrays. Example: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/v4.2/javadoc/ucar/ma2/ArrayFloat.html In any case, in the example I've provided you can get the number of dimensions with `sizes.length` so `sizes[0]` would yield that the first dimension has 10 "slots" (or whatever number is provided in the first element of array `sizes`).

Comment: @Thorn I'm getting that this is a case where it's "easier" or cleaner to just write up my own solution, i.e. the Java API only goes as far as providing a `Array.newInstance`. Seems weird to me, but OK... I can cook up a solution instead of relying more on the API.

Comment: I think I'd give up on `[]` arrays and switch to one of the List classes, with Integer, Float, etc wrappers for the primitives.  Of course, the generic stuff will make this harder, but it can probably be worked out.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm starting to think the same. I'm not insisting on an API-based solution, although that would be nice given the existence of `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding the solution instead of attempting to find/use array manipulation methods from the Java API (the only one below is `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Object[], int)`.

So, below are the methods I wrote. I did not test them extensively (I wouldn't be surprised if there are inefficiencies there, I just tried the first thing that appeared to work), so I expect that the following solution can be adapted to suit others' needs:

```
/**
 * Creates an instance of Object multi-dimensional arrays, with dimensions specified by the argument.
 * 
 * @example Create an array Object[4][20][30]:  
 * <pre>
 * Object[] array = newArray(new int[]{4,20,30});
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @param sizes The list of dimension lengths.
 * @return 
 */
public static Object[] newArray(int[] sizes) {
    Object[] result = null;
    if (sizes != null) {
        for(int n = sizes.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = new Object[sizes[n]];
            } else {
                Object[] oa = new Object[sizes[n]];
                for (int i = 0; i < sizes[n]; i++) {
                    oa[i] = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length);
                }
                result = oa;
            }
        }
        if (result == null) { result = new Object[1]; }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Get the value of a multi-dimensional array element given by a coordinate list.
 * 
 * @example Read the value at [2][14][27]:
 * <pre>
 * Object[] array;  // e.g. a int[4][20][30] created with newArray(int[])
 * int[] coord = new int[]{2,14,27};
 * Object value = getValue(array, coord);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @param array The coordinates of the array element.
 * @param coordinates
 * @return
 */
public static Object getValue(Object[] array, int[] coordinates) {
    Object result = null;
    if (array == null || coordinates == null || 0 > coordinates[0]||coordinates[0] > array.length) {
        result = null;
    } else {
        int x = coordinates[0];
        if (array[x] instanceof Object[]) {
            int[] c = new int[coordinates.length-1];
            for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { c[i] = coordinates[i + 1]; }
            result = getValue((Object[]) array[x], c);
        } else {
            result = array[x];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Set the value of a multi-dimensional array element given a list designating the element's coordinates.
 * 
 * @example Write a value to [1][0][7]:
 * <pre>
 * Object value;    // e.g. a float
 * Object[] array;  // e.g. a int[4][20][30] created with newArray(int[])
 * int[] coord = new int[]{1,0,7,};
 * setValue(array, coord, value);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @param array
 * @param coordinates
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
public static void setValue(Object[] array, int[] coordinates, Object value) {
    if (array == null || coordinates == null || array.length == 0 || coordinates.length == 0 || array.length < coordinates[0]||coordinates[0] < 0 ) {
        return;
    } else {
        int x = coordinates[0];
        if (array[x] != null && array[x].getClass().isArray()) {    // recurse
            int[] c = new int[coordinates.length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { c[i] = coordinates[i + 1]; }
            setValue((Object[]) array[x], c, value); 
        } else {
            array[x] = value;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question. This is really tricky because there doesn't seem to be a way to cast an object to an array of given dimensions. I couldn't find a way to get a proper multidimensional array object out of the created instance. But if you just want to get and set elements in the created array, you can use the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?> type = float.class; // this varies (I receive this)
    int[] sizes = new int[] { 1, 3 }; // this varies too, it could be e.g.
                                    // int[]{0} for a scalar
    Object f = Array.newInstance(type, sizes);
    set(f, new int[] { 0, 2 }, 3.0f);
    if (f instanceof Object[])
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) f));
    else {
        int l = Array.getLength(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            System.out.print(Array.get(f, i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void set(Object arr, int[] indexPath, Object value) {
    if (arr instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] temp= (Object[]) arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.length - 2; ++i) {
            temp = (Object[]) temp[indexPath[i]];
        }
        Array.set(temp[indexPath[indexPath.length - 2]],
            indexPath[indexPath.length - 1], value);
    } else {
        Array.set(arr,
                indexPath[0], value);
    }
}
```

The `set` method takes the index to set as an array. So `set(f, new int[] {0,0,1}, 3.0f);` should basically do `f[0][0][1] = 3.0f`

**EDIT**: Added a slightly ugly fix to handle single dimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the `java.lang.reflect.Array` class, there are other useful methods, such as `get(Object array, int index)` and `setFloat(Object array, int index, float f)`. Using combinations of these, one should be able to fill the entire multi-dimensional array.

Rough pseudocode:

```
Object level0 = createArray(...)
For i1 = 0 to (length of dimension 1) {
    Object level1 = get(level0, i1)
    For i2 = 0 to (length of dimension 2) {
        Object level2 = get(level1, i2)
        ...etc...
            For iM = 0 to (length of dimension M) {
                Object levelM = get(levelL, iM)
                For iN = 0 to (length of dimension N) {
                    setFloat(levelM, iN, 5.6f)
                }
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

If I'm reading the API correctly, something like this should work.

Comment: Read my comment. I tried that and it doesn't work because the get method expects single dimensional arrays as input.

Comment: +1 because this pointed me to `Array.set` which I was able to use in my solution.

Comment: @Thorn: What? Are you sure? `java.lang.reflect.Array.get(new int[4][4], 0);` seems to works on my end.